# Create Windows 8.1 USB Boot Disk to Boot in OSX Maverick

Tags: boot, usb, boot-camp, windows-8.1, osx-mavericks

After I installed Mac OSX Maverick 10.9 to my Mac Computer. I have a problem with installing Microsoft Windows 8.1 into my Mac my using Bootcamp.

I try some third party software such as Win USB Boot Maker and Rufus. These softwares can make USB Boot disk for non Mac computer however they cannot make it work with Mac.

Does anyone know how to create a working Windows 8.1 USB Boot Disk to work with Mac computer which run OSX Maverick?

Thank You! 
Pengan

Comment: This question I posted on AskDifferent may help http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x

Comment: Perhaps you could describe this problem you are experiencing? Can the bootable drive be created on your Mac bootcamp assistant?

Answer (score -1):

I sent a text to tech support at apple and learned that the maverick software is not compatible with windows 8.1 yet. They claim to be working on it